# Corrupted heap error when declaring a double* array

Tags: c++, matrix, double, heap-corruption

I'm currently working on finding the sum of squared distances of two matricies, the data is held in double* arrays. the first of them stays the same while the other is cycled through using a function that returns a 32x32 array between two indices.

However when i try and call "getTile(d,e)" after the first incrementation of "e" it throws a heap corruption exception:

```
double* Matrix::ssd(int i, int j, Matrix& rhs){
double sum = 0, val = 0; int g = 0, h=0;
double* bestMatch = new double[32*32]; double* sameTile = new double[32*32];    double* changeTile = new double[32*32]; 

for(int x = i-32; x <i; x++){
    for(int y = j-32; y <j; y++){
        sameTile[g*32+h] = data[x*N+y];
        h++;
    }g++; h = 0;
}

system("pause");

for(int d = 32; d<=512; d+=32){
    for(int e = 32; e<=512; e+=32){

        changeTile = rhs.getTile(d,e);

        for(int out = 0; out < 32; out++){
            for(int in = 0; in < 32; in++){
                val = sameTile[out*32+in] - changeTile[out*32+in];
                val = val*val;
                sum = sum + val;

            }       
        }
        cout << sum << endl;

        sum = 0; val = 0;

        system("pause");
    }   
}
```

The getTile(int i, int j) function:

```
double* Matrix::getTile(int i, int j){
double* tile = new double[32*32]; int g = 0; int h = 0;
for(int x=i-32; x<i; x++){
    for(int y=j-32; y<j; y++){
        tile[g*32+h] = data[x*N+y];
        h++;
    }
    cout << endl;
    g++;
}
return tile;
}
```

I believe the error occurs with the allocation of memory in the changeTile double*?

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: What is N and what are the inputs i and j input to the ssd() method? The definition/size of data[] would be helpful as well.

Comment: `tile` appears to be `return`ed from `getTile()` without having any data written into it. Is this intentional?

Comment: Your code would be a lot clearer to read were you to stick with one statement per line rather than trying to squeeze them in like `double* tile = new double[32*32]; int g = 0; int h = 0;` but where are all of these `new double[32*32]`s being `delete`d? Have you considered smart pointers or any of the `std::` containers? **`double*`s are not "arrays"**, they are pointers and should be treated as such.

Comment: @uesp N is the size of the x axis, in this case 512. data is declared using N and M, as in : double* data = new double[M*N];

Inputs i and j specify the location of the 32x32 tile that is being tested against every tile in the rhs matrix

Comment: @sarnold sorry, that was unintentional, edited to what it should be

Comment: Do you still have the bug in the corrected program?

Comment: @sarnold yes, although it is something to do with improperly declaring and accessing the double* pointers. Thanks for pointing (huhuhu) that out :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a bunch of issues in your code all related to improperly accessing array elements.

In the first loop the line:

```
 sameTile[g*32+h] = data[x*N+y];
```

at the very least underflows the data array. Consider if i=0, j=0, and N=512 then you are trying to access data[-16416] in the first pass of the loop.

Second issue is the getTile() method where you forget to reset `h` to 0 at the end of the inner loop (like you do in the ssd() method). This results in the overflow of tile[]

I would also double-check the line:

```
 changeTile = rhs.getTile(d, e);
```

and the method getTile() to ensure an array overflow doesn't occur on data[].

Overall I would suggest using proper std:: containers if at all possible. Using them correctly should completely eliminate this type of error. If you really do need to use raw pointers/arrays then you need to make sure all your indexing into them is as clear as possible in addition to bounds checking where needed.

Comment: Hey @uesp, thanks for the response. You'll have to excuse the scrappy bits of code, a lot of it needs refining and is just there to get a working program. The first loop you mentioned saved me some trouble, i was assuming the values that went in would never be lower than 32.

The issue is definately in the line changeTile = rhs.getTile(d, e);
 as the data being returned is not in the correct locations, it seems to be entering each element at every 32nd index value.

Once again thanks for the response :>